# Error when retrieving user using strongAuthenticationEmailAddress

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In my custom policy I am attempting to retrieve a user from the directory using the *strongAuthenticationEmailAddress* property as described in the following sample (line 135 in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml), however this does not appear to be working as expected.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-unique-email-across-social-identities

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingExternalIdpEmailAddress">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tempObjectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

After examining the traces in App Insights I found the following error.

*"Exception": { "Kind": "Handled", "HResult": "80131500", "Message": "An error occurred while retrieving User using identifier claim type "strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" in tenant "XXX". Error returned was 400/Request_UnsupportedQuery: Property 'strongAuthenticationEmailAddress' does not exist as a declared property or extension property."*

Am I missing something that needs to done before this will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only read a user by objectId, signInNames or alternativeSecurityId. This is an interface to the Microsoft Graph API, and this is limited by what it supports to retrieve an account by a unique identifier. StrongAuthEmail is not a unique identifier.

Comment: Looks like the sample goes against this so will double check with the creator.

Comment: Thanks Jas, I will await clarification.  The requirement is to ensure email addresses are unique across all accounts - for example to prevent someone signing up for a local account and then signing up with a social idp that uses the same email address.  Are there any other ways this can be achieved wholly within a custom policy?

Comment: Yes, you would store the email in the signInNames collection for this requirement, and the cross check would be against signInNames instead of strongAuthEmail.

Comment: I now have a working solution using the signInNames collection, many thanks for the info.